# Reading a fastq file and calculating how many bases have Phred base read quality

Tags: python, fastq

I need help solving the following question with Python3:
Write a Python program that reads a fastq file and calculate how many bases have Phred base read quality of zero, between 1 and 10 (inclusive), 11 and 20, 21 and 30, 31 and 40, and above 40.

I started with:

```
def decode(c):
    return ord(c) - 33

letters = "II93882$%@%%@"

values = map(decode, letters)
values = list(values)

print (values)
```

I'm attempting to figure out a way to get my final results to appear like this:

```
Base quality zero: XXX bases

Base quality 1-10: YYY bases

Base quality 11-20: ZZZ bases

Base quality 21-30: QQQ bases

Base quality 31-40: RRR bases

Base quality above 40: SSS bases
```

Comment: And the issue is...?

Comment: The code produces the values but how do I print them in the format above?

Comment: This is what I have started but I get a false value for the b .  a = values=0
print("Base quality zero:", a, "bases")
b = values>=1
print("Base quality 1-10:", b, "bases")

Comment: Don't put code that belong to the question in the comments, it cannot be followed/understood. Edit your question and add the relevant details. Add what you tried to get the expected results and pinpoint us to a specific issue with your code so we can help you.